# How to use `StaplerResponse rsp` in `AsyncResourceDisposer.doStopTracking()`

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to remove (stop tracking) trackig item from Jenkins AsyncResourceDisposer (`${JENKINS_URL}/administrativeMonitor/AsyncResourceDisposer`) via groovy scripts (`${JENKINS_URL}/script`).

According to the [Javadoc](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/resource-disposer/org/jenkinsci/plugins/resourcedisposer/AsyncResourceDisposer.html) and [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/resource-disposer-plugin/blob/436a31463c28cafd345a8bf37e8c1fd52ffe4c5b/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/resourcedisposer/AsyncResourceDisposer.java#L190)

```
// Javadoc
@Restricted(value=org.kohsuke.accmod.restrictions.DoNotUse.class)
public org.kohsuke.stapler.HttpResponse doStopTracking(@QueryParameter
  int id,
  org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerResponse rsp
)

// source code
@Restricted(DoNotUse.class)
@RequirePOST
public HttpResponse doStopTracking(@QueryParameter int id, StaplerResponse rsp) {
...
}
```

I'd like to know how to add `org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerResponse rsp` in `doStopTracking(int id, org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerResponse rsp)`:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.resourcedisposer.AsyncResourceDisposer

AsyncResourceDisposer disposer = AsyncResourceDisposer.get()
disposer.backlog.each {
  disposer.doStopTracking( it.id, <what should I put here> )
}
```

Current I can get the item id, and the other informaitons like below:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.resourcedisposer.AsyncResourceDisposer

AsyncResourceDisposer disposer = AsyncResourceDisposer.get()
String url = Jenkins.instance.rootUrl + disposer.url

disposer.getBacklog().each { item ->
  println "\n${item.id} : \t${url}/stopTracking/?id=${item.id} : \t${item.class.simpleName} : \n" +
          "\t${item.getLastState().getDisplayName()} : \n" + 
          "\t${item.getDisposable().node} : ${item.getDisposable().path}\n" +
          "\t${item.toString()}"
}
```

If I'm go to the url `"${url}/stopTracking/?id=${item.id}"` in browser (login first), the item **can be removed** after click <kbd>RETRY USING POST</kbd>  (as below)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

So... I'm using the API call `curl -H <crumbIssues> -X POST <url>` by passed the `disposer.doStopTracking(int, org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerResponse)` (**still really wants know how to use it**)

Before running the following script, [Strict Crumb Issuers Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/strict-crumb-issuer) is necessary to be installed and configured (or setup `-Dhudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer.EXCLUDE_SESSION_ID=true`) due to [SECURITY-626 : Improved CSRF protection](https://www.jenkins.io/security/advisory/2019-07-17/#SECURITY-626) since:

> obtain a crumb using the /crumbIssuer/api URL will now fail to perform actions protected from CSRF unless the scripts retain the web session ID in subsequent requests.

Here is details:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.resourcedisposer.AsyncResourceDisposer
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.strictcrumbissuer.StrictCrumbIssuer

AsyncResourceDisposer disposer = AsyncResourceDisposer.get()
StrictCrumbIssuer issuer = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.crumbIssuer
String jenkinsCrumb = "${issuer.crumbRequestField}:${issuer.crumb}"
String url = Jenkins.instance.rootUrl + disposer.url

disposer.getBacklog().each { item ->
  println "\n ~~> removeing ${item.id} : "
  [ 'bash', '-c', 'curl -s ' +
                       '-u <user>:<token> ' +
                       '-X POST ' +
                       "-H \"Content-Type: application/json\" " +
                       "-H \"Accept: application/json\" " +
                       "-H \"${jenkinsCrumb}\" " +
                       "${url}/stopTracking/?id=${item.id} "
  ].execute().with{
    def stdout = new StringBuffer()
    def stderr = new StringBuffer()
    it.waitForProcessOutput( stdout, stderr )
    println "EXIT CODE: ${it.exitValue()}"
    println "ERROR: ${stderr}"
    println "OUTPUT: ${stdout}"
  }
}
```

Although, I still have a question... As we know that if the groovy script running in `${JENKINS_URL}/script`, which means the "runner" is the administrator, so, how I can remove the specific user authorication `'-u <user>:<token>'` (by using the jenkins administrator authorication) in curl ?